I get an error that a value does not exist in the current content
I'm trying to learn making unity 2d game but I can't find a solution for the error and I'm new to C#, so I need your help.
This is the error I get :

Assets\SkeletonIdle.cs(10,120): error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'enemy' of 'SkeletonGroundedState.SkeletonGroundedState(Enemy, EnemyStateMachine, string, Enemy_Skeleton)'

And my code is here:
enter image description here
enter image description here
I tried to do a battle state for enemy and I expected when enemy sees me he will start to follow my character

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

The constructor for SkeletonGroundedState, which is the base class for SkeletonIdle, requires an enemy parameter (of type Enemy_Skeleton), and you're not passing one in your call to the base constructor.
This should do the trick:
public SkeletonIdle(Enemy _enemyBase, EnemyStateMachine _stateMachine, 
    string _animBoolName, Enemy_Skeleton enemy) : 
    base(_enemyBase, _stateMachine, _animBoolName, enemy)
{
}


@ArdaZengin Welcome to SO! If you have a second problem, you should ask a new question instead of commenting on an answer to the old one. Also, a second problem may suggest that your original code snippet was not an [mre], which is a requirement for code on SO.
